# Fastest way to merge a directory tree

Tags: python, linux

I have multiple directories of the form

```
foo/bar/baz/alpha_1/beta/gamma/files/uniqueFile1
foo/bar/baz/alpha_2/beta/gamma/files/uniqueFile2
foo/bar/baz/alpha_3/beta/gamma/files/uniqueFile3
```

What is the fastest way to merge these directories to a single directory structure like

```
foo/bar/baz/alpha/beta/gamma/files/uniqueFile1...uniqueFile3
```

I could write a python script to do that but is there a faster way to do that on a debian machine ? Can rsync help in this case ?

EDIT:

Apologies for not making it clear earlier, the depth in the examples is ~10-12 and I do not know the some directory names such as alpha*, these are randomly generated while throwing out logs. I was using **find** with wildcards to list these files earlier but now another level has been added in the path, that caused my find queries to take over a minute from 0.004s. So I am looking for a faster solution.

```
/known_fixed_path_5_levels/*/known_name*/*/fixed_path_2_levels/n_unique_files
```

has become

```
/known_fixed_path_5_levels/*/known_name*/*/xx*/fixed_path_2_levels/unique_file_1
/known_fixed_path_5_levels/*/known_name*/*/xx*/fixed_path_2_levels/unique_file_2
.
.
/known_fixed_path_5_levels/*/known_name*/*/xx*/fixed_path_2_levels/unique_file_n
```

I basically want to collect all those unique files into one place like how it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `find`:

```
mkdir --parents foo/bar/baz/alpha/beta/gamma/files; #create target directory if nessessary
find foo/bar/baz/alpha_[1-3]/beta/gamma/files -type f -exec cp {} foo/bar/baz/alpha/beta/gamma/files \;
```

Answer (score 1):

As question is not clear about *copying* or *moving*, there is two ways, **without** copy! Even second part don't effectively copy your data!

#### Simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command

Simply:

```
cd foo/bar/baz
mv -it alpha/beta/gamma/files alpha_*/beta/gamma/files/uniqueFile*
```

with `-i` switch to prevent overwritting.

This will work perfectly for small bunch of files.

#### More robust and adaptive [find](/questions/tagged/find) syntax

Or by using find:

```
cd foo/bar/baz
find alpha_* -type f -mindepth 3 -exec mv -it alpha/beta/gamma/files {} +
```

Advantage of using `find` are

- you could add a lot of flags like `-name`, `-mtime` and so on
- find will never try to pass more files to command (`mv`) that command line could hold.

#### `cp -al` specific ***UN*X*** concept

Under Un*x, you could create *hard-link* wich is not symbolic links, but a secondary entry in folder tree, for the same inode.

Nota: As only one inode has to be referenced, this could work only on same filesystem.

By using

```
cp -ialt alpha/beta/gamma/files alpha_*/beta/gamma/files/uniqueFile*
```

You will copy in one directory all inodes references, but keeping only one file for each.

#### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s *globstar* feature:

```
cd foo/bar/baz
shopt -s globstar
cp -alit alpha/beta/gamma/files alpha_*/**/uniqueFile*
```

Comment: In fine, I think the *fastest way* (and the quicker) is the last of my purposes